# My plot is cut off if a frametick is "0" but resized if a frametick is "0." Why?

Tags: plotting, bugs, version-9, mac-os-x

I have been trying to customize the frame ticks and frame label around a certain contour plot and am running into very strange behavior where the graphics will get cut off by `ImageSize` rather than being resized.

In the following example code (more or less minimal), note that all I have changed is a `0` to `0.` in the frametick specification.

What's going on here?

Minimal example:

```
ContourPlot[θ1 + θ2 == 0, {θ1, -3 π/2, π/2}, {θ2, -π/2, 3 π/2},
 FrameTicks -> {{{0, π}, None}, {{-π, 0.}, None}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(θ\), \(1\)]\)", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(θ\), \(2\)]\)"}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20}, ImageSize -> 200]

ContourPlot[θ1 + θ2 == 0, {θ1, -3 π/2, π/2}, {θ2, -π/2, 3 π/2},
 FrameTicks -> {{{0, π}, None}, {{-π, 0}, None}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(θ\), \(1\)]\)", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(θ\), \(2\)]\)"}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20}, ImageSize -> 200]
```

[image: input and output]

Comment: Sure, thanks. I just copied the code from my notebook; is there some easy trick so symbols don't turn into ASCII in general when I do that?

Comment: @Öskå If you remove the subscripts from `FrameLabel`, the problem disappears.  In this case, the subscripts seem to be needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: And it works fine for me: [here](http://i.imgur.com/Nt8Dokk.png). Thus, _Mathematica_ version? OS? Was it a clean kernel?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Works for me with `FrameLabel -> {Subscript["\[Theta]", "1"], Subscript["\[Theta]", "2"]}` though.. [here](http://i.imgur.com/FiFeGVC.png).

Comment: @Öskå  Try it with `FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), \(1\)]\)", 
  "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), \(2\)]\)"}`, which is what you get if you enter it with crtl-underscore.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Everything seems to work for me..: [here](http://i.imgur.com/2OMgv74.png) and [here](http://i.imgur.com/4mprZ1R.png). What am I missing?

Comment: If it matters, I'm running version 8.0.4.0, Mac OS X.

Comment: @j.c. Do you have the same issue with my edits of your code?

Comment: No, without the subscripts it renders fine.

Comment: Well, it works for me on _Mathematica 9_ on Windows 7. I assuming you will need someone else with a Mac :) While waiting for an other answer/feedback, `FrameLabel -> {Subscript["θ", "1"], Subscript["θ", "2"]}` should be a workaround with the same render, can you try?

Comment: It appears to be a problem with the Front End  on a Mac in V9.0.1 and V8.0.4 (and perhaps earlier) and typesetting.  It works fine in V10 on RPi with the same output transferred.  So I don't think it's a problem with the code produced by the Kernel.  It's probably a bug in the Front End that is being fixed (at least on RPi).

Comment: I just tried @Öskå's suggestion and that has the same issue.

Comment: @Öskå  I'm on a Mac, so you might be right that it is Mac-related only.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem in *Mathematica* 7 under Windows.

Comment: I can reproduce it on a mac in v9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an Issue on "9.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 24, 2013)"

There is "no" Issue on "10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014)"

```
ContourPlot[\[Theta]1 + \[Theta]2 == 
  0, {\[Theta]1, -3 \[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}, {\[Theta]2, -\[Pi]/2, 
  3 \[Pi]/2}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{0, \[Pi]}, None}, {{-\[Pi], 0.}, None}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), \(1\)]\)", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), \(2\)]\)"}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20}, ImageSize -> 200]

ContourPlot[\[Theta]1 + \[Theta]2 == 
  0, {\[Theta]1, -3 \[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}, {\[Theta]2, -\[Pi]/2, 
  3 \[Pi]/2}, FrameTicks -> {{{0, \[Pi]}, None}, {{-\[Pi], 0}, None}},
  FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), \(1\)]\)", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), \(2\)]\)"}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20}, ImageSize -> 200]
```

But note the "." on 0:

[image]